# What will be the movement of the block?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string, constrained-dynamics

[image]

Assume that there is no friction occurring.

**In case (A)-:**

*If the pulley is moved by X units in forward direction(which is shown through dotted lines) then clearly we can say that string L1 and L2 will also moves X units to keep them attached to it.Now,if the pulley moves in forward direction as shown then we can analyse that the string will move from L2 to L1 i.e the block will move in forward direction.

So from the above paragraph we can say that 2x units of string will move from L2 to L1 to keep the string around the pulley tight,**or in other words we can say that due to X units of displacement of the pulley the block displaced 2X units**,right.

**In case (B)-:**

*Now,in case (B) if the pulley displaces is in the direction shown,then it is clear that the block will move along the inclined in upward direction.So my question here is,**what is the relation between the block's movement and the pulley's movement,if the pulley is displaced by X units in the forward direction**.*

Comment: If you put another pulley at the top of the incline, the block will move the same distance. Without that you need more details about the geometry.

Comment: Sir,are you tryin to say that in the second case i.e case(B),if the pulley is moved  X units in forward direction,then the block will moves X units as well??

Comment: @PATRICK, is the incline fixed in place or is it free to move?

Comment: Yes, incline is fixed,sir,can you please help me with my question,I eagerly want to know the answers

Comment: With the second pulley, case B is the same as case A.